# Giving wrong records when join statement used for two queries

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC application. I have two queries and I want to get comment record from those two queries.

Query one

```
  var poList = (from po in db.PurchaseOrders 
                where po.Id > 0 
                select po into newPO
                select new { Name = newPO.PONo,  Id = newPO.Id });
```

Query Two

```
var poList2 = (db.Employees.Where(x => x.Id == 25)
              .Select(po => new { Name = po.PONo, Id = po.Id }));
```

Now I am trying to get common records from above two queries, using below statement

```
poList.Join(poList2, a => a.Name, b => b.Name, (a, b) => new { Name = b.Name, Id = b.Id });
```

but I am not getting common records at all.

What change I have to made in the statement ?

Comment: why do you need select po into newPO in first query?

Answer (score 1):

If "common records" mean records with same `Name` and `Id`, you can use [Intersect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345609.aspx) extension method.

```
var result = poList.Intersect(poList2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try?

```
poList.Concat(poList2).Distinct().ToList()
```